# Querying the cost of launching a instance from the AWS Pricing API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the AWS Pricing API:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html

The issue is that it has data like

```
"KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX" : {
  "sku" : "KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX",
  "productFamily" : "Compute Instance",
  "attributes" : {
    "servicecode" : "AmazonEC2",
    "location" : "US East (N. Virginia)",
    "locationType" : "AWS Region",
```

I don't know how to correlate `locationType` and `location` with the data I use to launch EC2 instances (e.g. in `us-east-1`).

Is there a way to know the cost of launching an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to work with large json documents. For OnDemand pricing of sku KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX for example:

```
curl -s https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json \
 | jq .terms.OnDemand.KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX
```

gives

```
{
  "KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX.JRTCKXETXF": {
    "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
    "sku": "KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX",
    "effectiveDate": "2016-12-01T00:00:00Z",
    "priceDimensions": {
      "KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
        "rateCode": "KV46EU5KJGKB53ZX.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
        "description": "$0.156 per Dedicated RHEL m1.medium Instance Hour",
        "beginRange": "0",
        "endRange": "Inf",
        "unit": "Hrs",
        "pricePerUnit": {
          "USD": "0.1560000000"
        },
        "appliesTo": []
      }
    },
    "termAttributes": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the question is how to *derive* `us-east-1` from `US East (N. Virginia)`.

Comment: "Is there a way to know the cost of launching an EC2 instance?". he just looked in the wrong place inside the json.

Comment: Hmm. You might be right.  I was focused on *"I don't know how to correlate `locationType` and `location`"*.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the presence of this cross-reference/mapping data within the structures provided by the price list API, and it is unfortunately not provided by [DescribeRegions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeRegions.html) in the EC2 API, either.

It is, however, readily available on the [Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region) page under general documentation.  From that info, you can build a simple dictionary or lookup table.

Comment: the Regions and Endpoints does not exactly match the names. For example, you can't find "US West (Los Angeles)"

Comment: Los Angeles is an exception because it isn't a region, it's a [local zone](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/localzones/) that's connected to the us-west-2 region.

Answer (score 1):

Just built it myself. I know it will not be updated but...

NB: China is missing from this list I extracted from AWS pricing user interface

```json
{
    "AWS GovCloud (US-East)": "us-gov-east-1",
    "AWS GovCloud (US-West)": "us-gov-west-1",
    "Africa (Cape Town)": "af-south-1",
    "Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)": "ap-east-1",
    "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)": "ap-south-1",
    "Asia Pacific (Osaka-Local)": "ap-northeast-3",
    "Asia Pacific (Seoul)": "ap-northeast-2",
    "Asia Pacific (Singapore)": "ap-southeast-1",
    "Asia Pacific (Sydney)": "ap-southeast-2",
    "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)": "ap-northeast-1",
    "Canada (Central)": "ca-central-1",
    "EU (Frankfurt)": "eu-central-1",
    "EU (Ireland)": "eu-west-1",
    "EU (London)": "eu-west-2",
    "EU (Milan)": "eu-south-1",
    "EU (Paris)": "eu-west-3",
    "EU (Stockholm)": "eu-north-1",
    "Middle East (Bahrain)": "me-south-1",
    "South America (Sao Paulo)": "sa-east-1",
    "US East (Boston)": "us-east-1-bos-1",
    "US East (Houston)": "us-east-1-iah-1",
    "US East (Miami)": "us-east-1-mia-1",
    "US East (N. Virginia)": "us-east-1",
    "US East (Ohio)": "us-east-2",
    "US East (Verizon) - Atlanta": "us-east-1-wl1-atl1",
    "US East (Verizon) - Boston": "us-east-1-wl1",
    "US East (Verizon) - Dallas": "us-east-1-wl1-dfw1",
    "US East (Verizon) - Miami": "us-east-1-wl1-mia1",
    "US East (Verizon) - New York": "us-east-1-wl1-nyc1",
    "US East (Verizon) - Washington DC": "us-east-1-wl1-was1",
    "US West (Los Angeles)": "us-west-2-lax-1",
    "US West (N. California)": "us-west-1",
    "US West (Oregon)": "us-west-2",
    "US West (Verizon) - Las Vegas": "us-west-2-wl1-las1",
    "US West (Verizon) - San Francisco Bay Area": "us-west-2-wl1",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `regionCode` instead of `location`